# How to write and read data from plist to tableview

Tags: objective-c, plist, bookmarks

Hi I am trying to make bookmarks for my browser. 
Title of Page, Url of Page, any Comments related to page.

I tried to save it in `plist`, but unsuccessful. Can anyone can help me to save these thing to plist and retrive in table view. So, when user tap on title it will open url in `UIWebView`.

Here is the code I have tried, so far:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bookmarks.plist"]; 

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
      NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bookmarks" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
}
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

NSString *writeUrl = @"Page URL One";
NSString *writeTitle = @"Page Title One";
NSString *writeComment = @"Page comments";

[data setObject:[NSString stringWithString:writeUrl] forKey:@"url"];
[data setObject:[NSString stringWithString:writeTitle] forKey:@"title"];
[data setObject:[NSString stringWithString:writeComment] forKey:@"comment"];
[data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];

NSMutableDictionary *savedUrl = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

NSString *value;
value = [[savedUrl objectForKey:@"url"] stringValue];
NSLog(@"%@", value);
```

UPDATE: I successfully saved and retrieved data to and from plist. Issue is comming in this line

```
value = [[savedUrl objectForKey:@"url"] stringValue];
```

By removing stringValue solve the problem.

```
 value = [savedUrl objectForKey:@"url"];
```

Now My second issue. I make three items named url, title, comment, types String in plist file. 
How can i store different urls. Like

name website: inforains
url: inforains.com
title: Info Rains
comment: good website articles

name website: hitechnology
url: hitechnology.com
title: Hitechnology
comment: hmmm

ans soo on..

how can I store data like this.. so all name website will show on tableview and when user click on anyone, data related to that website will show. I hope i clear my question.

Comment: You should indent your code. Cmd+a then Ctrl+i

Comment: At least, it should be: value = [[**savedURL** objectForKey:@"url"] stringValue];

Comment: @Geraud.ch yes changed and solve by removing stringValue. Updated my answer with another issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
value = [[savedStock objectForKey:@"url"] stringValue];
```

to

```
value = [savedUrl objectForKey:@"url"];
```

because you are saving NSString in dictionary... not NSNumber.

Second issue:

```
//create mutable array to save all objects
NSMutableArray *objectsArray = [data objectForKey:@"objectsArray"];
if(!objectsArray) {
    objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

//create and add dictionary into array
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"url1", @"title1", @"comment2",nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"url", @"title", @"comment",nil]];

[objectsArray addObject:dictionary];

[data setObject:objectsArray forKey:@"objectsArray"];

[data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];


// to read data
NSMutableDictionary *savedUrl = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
NSMutableArray *objectsArraySAved = [savedUrl objectForKey:@"objectsArray"];
for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in objectsArraySAved) {
    NSLog(@"URL %@", [dic valueForKey:@"url"]);
}
```

Comment: yes solved. now second issue is coming.. updated my questing.

Comment: yes it solved second issue.. Please also tell me how can I show these plist on table view and when user tap on the title table view cell it shows url, title, comment.

Comment: I find one tutoril which solve my read problem. But I dont know how to write like that plist with codes. here is the link.. any help. http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-fetch-data-using-plist-property-list/

Answer (score 2):

To store multiple records as three items named url, title, comment, types String in plist file
change types from string to dictionary and store data in each dictionary individually for key as 1,2,3 ... 
OR 
Use three mutable array for each url,title and comment and add object at index 0 at the time of saving it.
and access them when required as nsmutable array.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure [data writeToFile: path atomically:YES]; works? It returns a BOOL, you should check it.
Are you sure savedURL != nil?

Comment: yes BOOL is working.. but savedUrl is nil. solve by removing stringValue.

Answer (score 1):

For your new problem, you should put all your dictionaries in a mutable array.

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[bookmarkArray addObject:data];
```

Comment: then? how to access dictionary to save data and retrive specific data

Comment: then [bookmarkArray objectAtIndex:X]; if you know X or iterate in the bookMarkArray to access your dictionaries.